# How can you change \mathbb characters to the old version?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, blackboard

If you look at older documents the `\mathbb` characters appear different. For example they are sans serif. I don't know how I can use that set of characters instead of the current default.

If you are not sure what version I am talking about load the package fourier and then use `\mathbb{C}` for example to see the difference. No other package beside fourier does that and I want to know how to do it with other packages.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but let's see if I can understand it. What you want is to obtain the `\mathbb` font from the `fourier` package but *without* changing the rest of the fonts?

Comment: You can't use them yet without seriously modifying your LaTeX documents and workflow, but the blackboard bold character in the STIX font also look similar to `fourier`.

Comment: Btw, for those that do not want to try it: This is what the `fourier` `\mathbb` font looks like: http://www.caramdir.at/uploads/tex.SE/fourier-mathbb.png

Comment: @ Juan. Yes and if you look at older Math publication what is in fourier now used to be the standard some 20 years ago.

Comment: @hesam: when i started using tex, the fonts msxm and msym were in use; they were only available in archaic metafont (which wouldn't compile by the mid-80s when i started), and some (iirc) pxl files at a low resolution.  the ams paid for a new version to be written, and there was outcry back then about the lost serifs (i forget what barbara beeton -- then as now, the public face of the ams in the tex world -- said about the complaints).  anyway, i think yours is the first complaint i've seen, about this, for something like 20 years!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a hack that seems to do the work, it actually comes from the source of the `fourier` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{futm}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{futm}{m}{n}{
  <-> s * [.92] fourier-bb
  }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{Ufutm}{U}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{Ufutm}

\begin{document}
Hello World $\mathbb{C}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does work. I was hoping there would be a more clean solution like you load some package or activate some option of the \mathbb{} command. But thank you.

Comment: Yo could try the solutions proposed by others (which seem easier) to check if they work for you. Otherwise you can throw this code in a .sty file and include it using `\usepackage`. In any case, if you like this answer please feel free tu up-vote/accept it :)

Answer (score 8):

The [Symbols Guide](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) has the following suggestions for blackboard bold fonts:

[image: bb fonts]

In particular, `bbold`, `mathbbol` and `mbboard` provide sans-serif fonts. The last two also provide additional symbols in blackboard bold.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [msym](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/msym/) package, which provides an older version of the AMS blackboard bold font (but it only has the letters C, N, R, S, Z).

Comment: msym "looks good", but has no map file or (la)tex macros (and it isn't in tl or miktex) ... and of course there's no licence statement to tell us whether it's permissible to put it right.  further investigation obviously needed!